# Async error while sending mail in MVC identitiy

Tags: asp.net-mvc, vb.net

I'm using MVC identity in one of my projects.  I keep receiving the following error after registering a user:

> "An asynchronous module or handler completed while an asynchronous
>   operation was still pending."

I have implemented `Await` in my controller and cant see where I'm going wrong, if anyone could please advise. Many thanks.

Controller:

```
    <HttpPost>
    <AllowAnonymous>
    <ValidateAntiForgeryToken>
    Public Async Function Register(model As RegisterViewModel) As Task(Of ActionResult)
        If ModelState.IsValid Then
            Dim user = New ApplicationUser() With {
            .UserName = model.Email,
            .Email = model.Email,
            .FullName = model.FullName,
            .UserSettings = New UserSettings() With {
            .OrderEnabled1 = True, .OrderEnabled2 = True, .OrderEnabled3 = True, .OrderEnabled4 = True, .OrderEnabled5 = True, .OrderEnabled6 = True, .OrderEnabled7 = True,
            .OrderInput1 = 1, .OrderInput2 = 2, .OrderInput3 = 3, .OrderInput4 = 4, .OrderInput5 = 5, .OrderInput6 = 6, .OrderInput7 = 7,
            .VAT = VATconst
            }
        }

            user.UserSettings.Id = user.Id

            Dim result = Await UserManager.CreateAsync(user)

            If result.Succeeded Then
                UserManager.AddToRole(user.Id, "User")

                Dim code = Await UserManager.GenerateEmailConfirmationTokenAsync(user.Id)
                Dim callbackUrl = Url.Action("ConfirmEmail", "Account", New With {.userId = user.Id, .code = code}, protocol:=Request.Url.Scheme)
                Await UserManager.SendEmailAsync(user.Id, "Confirm your account", "Please confirm your account by clicking <a href=""" & callbackUrl & """>here</a>")

                Return RedirectToAction("Index", "Users")

            End If
            AddErrors(result)
        End If

        Return View(model)
    End Function
```

Email Service:

```
Public Class EmailService
Implements IIdentityMessageService

Public Function SendAsync(message As IdentityMessage) As Task Implements IIdentityMessageService.SendAsync
    ' Plug in your email service here to send an email.

    ' Create the mail message
    Dim msg As New MailMessage()
    msg.To.Add(message.Destination)

    Dim address As New MailAddress("*****@gmail.com")
    msg.From = address
    msg.Subject = message.Subject
    msg.Body = message.Body
    msg.IsBodyHtml = True

    'Configure an SmtpClient to send the mail.            
    Dim client As New SmtpClient()
    client.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network
    client.EnableSsl = True
    client.Host = "smtp.gmail.com"
    client.Port = 25

    Dim credentials As New NetworkCredential("*****@gmail.com", "****")
    client.Credentials = credentials

    'Send the msg
    Return client.SendMailAsync(msg)

End Function
End Class
```

Comment: Very odd. For the most part, the only time you will get this exception is if you've got asynchronous code calling an async void method. However, I don't see any place in the posted code where you're doing that. Using `async void` is an anti-pattern anyways, so check your project for places where you might be doing that and use `async Task` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make your Service function async and await too.